# OData PUT request getting response of "428 Precondition Required"

Tags: rest, odata, postman, http-response-codes

I'm sending a PUT request (using PostMan) to the TripPin service from the [OData Basic Tutorial](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/).

```
PUT http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')
```

The body:

```
{
"@odata.id": "serviceRoot/Airlines('FM')"
}
```

The response I'm getting is `428 (Precondition Required)`. There is already a question [OData : Why am I getting HTTP 428 (Precondition Required) error while performing an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210658/odata-why-am-i-getting-http-428-precondition-required-error-while-performing), and the answer there states that:

> your service uses optimistic locking and expects an If-Match
>   header, containing the ETag of the entity, in the request

But the answer doesn't make it clear how to put a correct If-Match header, and I couldn't find any examples.

So how can I fix this error (by adding an If-Match header with the ETag or otherwise)?

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround in http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/operations/

> When issuing a PUT, MERGE or DELETE request, clients need to indicate
>   an ETag in the If-Match HTTP request header. If for a given client it
>   is acceptable to overwrite any version of the Entry in the server,
>   then the value "*" may be used instead. If a given Entry has an ETag
>   and a client attempts to modify or delete the Entry without an
>   If-Match header servers should fail the request with a 412 response
>   code.

Putting '*' for `If-Match` works and the server now returns `204 No Content` and my changes are successfully made.

[image]

Otherwise we have to put the contents of the `odata.etag` field from the GET request. For example for `"@odata.etag": "W/\"08D417AED09F4758\""`, we put `W/"08D417AE4EA83DB1"` into the `If-Match` header.